# Policeman's large Elvish dagger (5)

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

The clue is:

> Policeman's large Elvish dagger (5)

The answer is:

> Sting

How is the answer derived?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a double definition.

[Sting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_(musician)), the musician, was a member of the band *The Police*, hence a 'Policeman'.

Meanwhile there is a 'large Elvish dagger' called '[Sting](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Sting)' that appears in the books *The Hobbit* and *Lord of the Rings*.

Comment: Of course it is!  I feel silly.

Comment: Why do you say Sting was a "large Elvish dagger"? The article you link says "Though just a dagger by standard of the Elves, Sting made a perfect short-sword for a Hobbit, although it was still rather small."

Comment: @MartinSmith Not my words - that's the wording of the clue itself. Take it up with the original setter! ;-)

Comment: @MartinSmith Sting was by construction a large Elvish dagger; the fact that it was also the right size to serve as a sword for a hobbit doesn't change its original nature.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a double definition: A policeman who's [at] large could be on a sting, and of course [Sting](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Sting) is the dagger that Bilbo uses as a sword in *The Hobbit*.

I'm not 100% sure it's fair to elide the "at" in "at large," but crosswordese does what it does.

Comment: I think it might be more that Sting was the lead singer of *The Police*, i.e. he was the "large" of the band?  I've heard the word used to refer to the leader or person in charge.  The clue would probably be equally effective without the word "large" in it at all, TBH.  Having it there just confuses things.